# Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString); vs Console.WriteLine(obj);

Tags: c#, .net

Is it better to write `obj.ToString()` in this example or maybe just `obj`?

```
Object obj = new Object();
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
// or
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

And what is the real difference? Is it a better style of coding?

Comment: It's the same. In both cases `.ToString` will be called

Comment: Yes,however the question is what's better to use and why?Or it depend on you?

Comment: There is no difference from usage point of view. So it's up to your personal\team preferences. The only one difference is that Console.WriteLine might not displaying anything if `obj` is null, and `obj.ToString()` will fail with NRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString())` and `Console.WriteLine(obj)` appears to be the same, but you call different methods.

If you call [Console.WriteLine(object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx) a null check is done. If negative, the `ToString()` method of the object is called.

If you call [Console.WriteLine(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb(v=vs.110).aspx) a null check is done. If negative, the string is written directly.

Generally, just sending the object is fine, ignore to call the `ToString()` method. It's redundant. If you call it though ensure you're not falling into the `null` trap. Call it like this: `obj?.ToString()` or be more explicit with the `null`:

```
Console.WriteLine(obj == null ? "NULL" : obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

When you pass an `Object` to the `Console.WriteLine()`, it will first check if it's implementing the `IFormattable` interface. `Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());` will call the `ToString` directly.

---

Update: *(regarding the comment of Rasik)*

This example shows the difference in output of the two methods. *(parameter `String` vs `Object`)*

```
public class MyObject : IFormattable
{
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return "IFormattable";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "ToString";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new MyObject();

        Console.WriteLine(obj);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
IFormattable
ToString
```

Comment: I doubt that Console.Writeline will make a check if the type of input parameter implements IFormattable or not? Here is the signature of the interface API: `IFormattable.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)` So essentially it requires an IFormatProvider as well but non of the overloads of `Console.WriteLine` function takes a reference to an object of type IFormatProvider as argument. It simply calls the virtual, parameterless `ToString()` method defined in the base "Object" class or an overridden ToString method in the type of the object being passed as arguments to `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: The underlying `Console.Out.WriteLine()` does the check. The `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;` will be passed in the `formatProvider` _(if no other is specified)_

Comment: Very thorough explanation. Now things are crystal clear. You get my +1.

Answer (score 0):

As Quality Catalyst has said, when you use **Console.WriteLine** directly with a string ou object, you are really using different overloads of the method; that in this case, there is no difference in behavior.

I hope this helps you!